# Libgit2 and msysgit character encoding file content inconsistencies

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, libgit2

I'm creating a tool using LibGit2 and have some inconsistencies compared to using msysgit with file contents for some special cases.

Commiting and pushing a file containing only the character 'å' (iso8859-1) followed by a new line and then cloning this remote repository to another directory results in the two files not being binary same.

Hex content of original file commited:
E5 0D 0A (å CR LF)

Hex content of the cloned file in the other repository:
E5 0A (å LF)

I only get this behavior using LibGit2 (core.autocrlf = true). If I clone using msysgit the files will be binary same.

If the file contains only a-z characters this behavior is not present.

Why do I get this behavior and how can I get LibGit2 to behave just like msysgit?

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/msysgit/EDD3RipNeBQ/discussion)?

Comment: The char you mention in the second paragraph is different from the one in the example, is this an oversight? How are you committing? With libgit2, git? What's `core.autocrlf` on each of the repositories?

Comment: @CarlosMartínNieto The char is a typo, it should be 'å'. I'm using git for committing, core.autocrlf is true.

Comment: Thanks @kostix, the exact same problem!